# Linking multiple interfaces in python using tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

*Thank you for reading. I am new to coding and have googled this problem and consulted text resources without success. I do not have access to a teacher. I did my best to create a version of the problem in as simple a way as I could. I greatly appreciate your time and effort in helping me to solve this problem.*

I am working in Python using IDLE and tkinter.

I am trying to link two interfaces using tkinter. I designed the first interface to ask for two entries, (defined as factor1 and factor2). I also put a button on the first interface. I am trying to create a command for the button to open the second interface.

Once, the second interface is open, the second interface is designed to use the user inputs into the two entries from the first interface (defined as factor1 and factor2) as labels.

```
#First Interface

from tkinter import *
from tkinter.messagebox import *

master = Tk()
master.title('Getting Started')

label1 = Label(master, text = 'what is factor 1:', relief = 'groove', width = 19)
label2 = Label(master, text = 'what is factor 2:', relief = 'groove', width = 19)
factor1 = Entry(master, relief = 'groove', width = 12)
factor2 = Entry(master, relief = 'groove', width = 12)


button2 = Button(master, text = 'Go', relief = 'groove', width = 25)

label1.grid( row = 1, column = 1, padx = 10 )
label2.grid( row = 2, column = 1, padx = 10 )
factor1.grid( row = 1, column = 2, padx = 10 )
factor2.grid( row = 2, column = 2, padx = 10 )
button2.grid( row = 3, column = 1, columnspan = 2)

#Second Interface

from tkinter import *
from tkinter.messagebox import *

mydict = {'good':0.75, 'outstanding': 1}

master = Tk()
label1 = Label(master, text = 'proposal', relief = 'groove', width = 19)
label2 = Label(master, text = factor1, relief = 'groove', width = 19)
label3 = Label(master, text = factor2, relief = 'groove', width = 19)
label4 = Label(master, text = 'Proposal Score', relief = 'groove', width = 19)
label5 = Label(master, text = '1', relief = 'groove', width = 12)
entry1 = Entry(master, relief = 'groove', width = 12)
entry2 = Entry(master, relief = 'groove', width = 12)
blank1 = Entry(master, relief = 'groove', width = 12)

def show_answer():
    c = float( mydict[entry1.get()]) *float( mydict[entry2.get()])
    blank1.insert(0, c)

button1 = Button(master, text = 'Calculate Proposal Scores', relief = 'groove', width = 25, command = show_answer)

label1.grid( row = 1, column = 1, padx = 10 )
label2.grid( row = 1, column = 2, padx = 10 )
label3.grid( row = 1, column = 3, padx = 10 )
label4.grid( row = 1, column = 4, padx = 10 )
label5.grid( row = 2, column = 1, padx = 10 )
entry1.grid( row = 2, column = 2, padx = 10 )
entry2.grid( row = 2, column = 3, padx = 10 )
blank1.grid( row = 2, column = 4, padx = 10 )
button1.grid( row = 3, column = 2, columnspan = 2)
```

Right now, both interfaces are in one IDLE document. However, I am unsure whether they should be kept in separate files.

My questions are:

Should I use one IDLE file or two?

If one, how do I make two separate interfaces in one idle file?

If two, how do I link the information, so that the second interface can use the inputs entered in the first interface?

How do I create a command so that the button is able to signal to close interface one and open interface two?

I understand this question may be complicated. If you have any additional books or resources to recommend I would greatly appreciate it. Additionally, if you have any suggestions on how I could make this question better, I would greatly appreciate it. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whether you use one file or two is completely up to you. If the code was very long, I'd recommend splitting into two files, but it's short enough that there's nothing wrong with keeping it all in the same file.

What you *should* do, however, is to separate the code into two *functions*. One function will open the first window and ask the user to input the two factors. Then when the button is pressed, it will take the two factors and use them as arguments for the second function (which opens the 2nd window). The code looks like this:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.messagebox import *


def first_interface():
    master = Tk()
    master.title('Getting Started')

    label1 = Label(master, text = 'what is factor 1:', relief = 'groove', width = 19)
    label2 = Label(master, text = 'what is factor 2:', relief = 'groove', width = 19)
    factor1 = Entry(master, relief = 'groove', width = 12)
    factor2 = Entry(master, relief = 'groove', width = 12)

    def start_second_interface():
        f1 = float(factor1.get())
        f2 = float(factor2.get())
        second_interface(f1, f2)

    button2 = Button(master, text = 'Go', relief = 'groove', width = 25, command=start_second_interface)

    label1.grid( row = 1, column = 1, padx = 10 )
    label2.grid( row = 2, column = 1, padx = 10 )
    factor1.grid( row = 1, column = 2, padx = 10 )
    factor2.grid( row = 2, column = 2, padx = 10 )
    button2.grid( row = 3, column = 1, columnspan = 2)


def second_interface(factor1, factor2):
    mydict = {'good':0.75, 'outstanding': 1}

    master = Toplevel()
    label1 = Label(master, text = 'proposal', relief = 'groove', width = 19)
    label2 = Label(master, text = factor1, relief = 'groove', width = 19)
    label3 = Label(master, text = factor2, relief = 'groove', width = 19)
    label4 = Label(master, text = 'Proposal Score', relief = 'groove', width = 19)
    label5 = Label(master, text = '1', relief = 'groove', width = 12)
    entry1 = Entry(master, relief = 'groove', width = 12)
    entry2 = Entry(master, relief = 'groove', width = 12)
    blank1 = Entry(master, relief = 'groove', width = 12)

    def show_answer():
        c = float( mydict[entry1.get()]) *float( mydict[entry2.get()])
        blank1.insert(0, c)

    button1 = Button(master, text = 'Calculate Proposal Scores', relief = 'groove', width = 25, command = show_answer)

    label1.grid( row = 1, column = 1, padx = 10 )
    label2.grid( row = 1, column = 2, padx = 10 )
    label3.grid( row = 1, column = 3, padx = 10 )
    label4.grid( row = 1, column = 4, padx = 10 )
    label5.grid( row = 2, column = 1, padx = 10 )
    entry1.grid( row = 2, column = 2, padx = 10 )
    entry2.grid( row = 2, column = 3, padx = 10 )
    blank1.grid( row = 2, column = 4, padx = 10 )
    button1.grid( row = 3, column = 2, columnspan = 2)


first_interface()
```

This has solved all your problems in a single simple step: The code is neatly organized, and you can easily pass the two factors to the second window.

(P.S. I've used a `tk.TopLevel` instead of a `tk.Tk` for the second window. There should be exactly one `tk.Tk` instance in each program. If you use more than one, you're going to run into problems.)